# What is the main difference between Google app engine and Google ML engine when hosting tensorflow models for prediction?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-ml

I have a locally trained tensorflow model that needs to be hosted on a cloud service so that I can call upon it from within my flutter app to make predictions on input data.

When searching for solutions, I found that people have achieved the above by using both ML engine (calling the model predict via firebase functions) and App engine (using REST API to get predictions from the hosted model)

If both achieve the same result, why have two services? Is one faster than the other? or cheaper? Other than having a front facing app, are the both services the same?

Comment: Can you share the link of Tensorflow Serving on App Engine? Can you also share your model requirements (size of the model, number of CPU required, GPU, batch or online serving,....)?

Comment: Hi, don't know what link you are referring to, is it the documentation for app engine model hosting? As for my model, its size is 500-700MB, 4 core CPU would be enough, no GPU needed, online serving preferred as I would send predict request from my app. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve a model with Tensorflow Serving, you need... tensorflow serving, a binary to install in your environment.

So, with App Engine standard, you can't install any binary, you can only define dependencies to use.

With App Engine Flexible, you can set a [custom runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes) and provide a Dockerfile to customize it. This time you can't install TensorFlow Serving and serve your model on App Engine flex.

*Note: App Engine Standard scale to 0, and you don't pay when you don't process any request. App Engine flexible scale to 1, and so, you pay at least 1 instance full time, traffic or not.*

---

On the AI Platform side, you have [2 types of machine type](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction). the legacy `MLS1` with a behavior and a pricing very close to App Engine Standard (scale to 0 so, pay at least 15 minutes of runtime if an instance is created,...) but with tensorflow serving installed and so, you can use it to serve prediction.

However, the `MLS1` type support models up to 500Mb, it shouldn't be suitable for you.

The `N1` type is the new platform for AI PLatform online prediction serving (batch not possible on this type of machine). More CPU, GPUs, Memory, model up to 2Gb,... But, like App Engine Flexible, the platform scale to 1, and so you pay even if you don't serve traffic.

*Note: The AI Platform serving machines are optimized for prediction and tensorflow. App Engine is optimized for general purposed, and especially web serving.*

---

I performed a [talk about the differences last year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x7gSuJ_Ugk)

---

From there, I wasn't satisfied about these solutions. I found a 3rd way to serve models, this time with Cloud Run. I [wrote an article with the model already package in the container](https://medium.com/google-cloud/portable-prediction-with-tensorflow-and-cloud-run-669c1c73ebd1) (longer container start (cold start) but more efficient in request processing) and [another one to load the model on each request](https://medium.com/google-cloud/on-demand-small-batch-predictions-with-cloud-run-and-embedded-tf-469242d66c3b) (longer processing time, but reusable for different type of models).

On this last one, I published an open source solution. I can update it with your requirement if needed.

---

*Final note: it's maybe possible to serve tensorflow model on App Engine Standard with a TensorflowJS model and NodeJS runtime environment. I never tested (I'm neither a data scientist nor a NodeJS dev)*